# Error with my batch script when calling sql, but gives expected result in SSMS

Tags: sql-server, windows, batch-file

I'm trying to build (my first) Windows batch file, to call a SQL command returning a value and setting it as a variable before doing more work.

I am getting the following error:

> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near THEN

When I execute the script, yet it gives 'HEALTHY' as expected in SSMS. Here is this part of my script:

```
@echo on

setlocal
set SQL_SERVER=MYSQLSERVER
set SQL_DB=MYDB

set SQL=SELECT CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE,MAX(LogDate), GETDATE())  > 5 THEN 'RESTART' ELSE 'HEALTHY' END AS RESULT FROM myschema.mytable

:loop


set SQL_RESULT=
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('sqlcmd -S %SQL_SERVER% -d %SQL_DB% -h -1 -W -s "," -Q "%SQL%"') do set SQL_RESULT=%%i

echo SQL result returned: %SQL_RESULT%
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you output `echo %SQL%` or the command inside `()`? I suspect it's getting truncated or altered, maybe due to the `'` characters? This is a pretty fundamental debugging technique (also we can't necessarily help either unless we know what you're actually sending to SQL Server).

Comment: An unprotected **`>`** character is for redirection, in cmd.exe and batch files. It therefore needs protection!

Comment: @Compo good catch, I was going to mention that character too but I ran out of edit grace period. :-)

Comment: "I'm trying to build my first windows batch file" is not something one wants to read in 2023. Please, use powershell or something, even vbscript is better